# Python subprocess.Popen slow under uWSGI

Tags: python, performance, popen, uwsgi

I've set up a development server running Cherokee on Fedora 14, using uWSGI to interface with my WSGI application.

When the application is hit with the first request, I spawn a process like so:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen(['bash'])  # bash is just an example; the problem happens with all programs
```

The first request takes 10-15 seconds to complete (subsequent ones take less than a second).
Without the creation of the Popen object, the first request only takes about 2-3 seconds to complete. When I execute the same Popen request from a Python shell, it's instantaneous.

What could be causing this behaviour? Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`--close-on-exec`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#close-on-exec)

Otherwise your new process will inherit the socket

(this is a UNIX standard behaviour)

Comment: Could you explain further? What exactly do you mean by "inherit the socket"? (I'm new to this stuff)

Comment: Just tried adding `<close-on-exec />` to my uWSGI XML config file and it fixed the problem. Thanks so much! This seems to be an undocumented option of uWSGI though -- I can't find it in the [docs](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc). Any chance of it being added soon?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29 in unix whenever you spawn a new process it will get all the file descriptor opened by the parent. So when you call Popen in the worker, the new process will inherith the webserver socket. In this case the connection will not be closed until the subprocess ends. --close-on-exec is reported in uwsgi --help, but you are right it must be included in the web docs

Comment: @roberto: Interesting. So the delay was caused because the webserver socket was being handed down to the subprocess? With close-on-exec, is the webserver socket closed on the parent process or just the spawning subprocess?

Comment: close-on-exec is a flag you set on sockets. It does not modify the fork() behaviour but automatically close the socket when you call exec() (and Popen is a simple fork()+exec() call). So the connection between the worker and the webserver is still opened. You can safely use it, take in account that flup force this feature by default. (uWSGI does not do it, to allow tricks like detaching sessions)

Comment: Neat! Thanks for all the info

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to handle this in your python code, you have the option to pass close_fds=True to [Popen()](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) then any sockets will not be inherited by the forked process.