# uWSGI websocket seems to wait for timeout before replying first time

Tags: python, websocket, uwsgi

I'm using the basic uWSGI [websockets_echo.py](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/tests/websockets_echo.py) example (copied into my `server.py`), and running the server with (just want basic http vs the https their example uses):

```
uwsgi --http :80 --http-websockets --wsgi-file /srv/www/server.py
```

When I connect to the website, the browser instantly responds with an alert saying that the websocket is connected.  Great!  I can also see that the browser immediately sends back the `ciao` to the webserver.  The issue is that the webserver seems to be blocking on this line of `websockets_echo.py`:

```
msg = uwsgi.websocket_recv()
```

**Approximately 30 seconds after the client sends the message to the sever, the server echo's it back to the client**, and now any messages from the client are echo'd almost immediately back.  The very first response seems to have to wait for some sort of timeout though.  I'm likely missing some very basic [option](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html), but the option list is massive, and the documentation on each is sparse.  I've tried various combinations of: [--http-raw-body](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#http-raw-body), [--gevent 100](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#gevent), [--async 30](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#async), [--enable-threads](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#enable-threads), but can't seem to find the right options (assuming this is my issue).

I'm using:

- uWSGI 2.0.6 (64bit)
- Ubuntu Linux 14
- Python version 2.7.6

I can post the initial server printout, but its a bit of a wall of text, so I'm skipping, unless someone thinks its necessary.

**I'd like to know how to eliminate this initial 30 second wait time (or what exactly I'm doing wrong)**.  Thanks.

**EDIT:** strace outupt follows:

```
[pid   728] 10:02:27.893237 epoll_wait(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   727] 10:02:27.893786 <... epoll_wait resumed> {{EPOLLIN, {u32=3, u64=3}}}, 1, -1) = 1
[pid   727] 10:02:27.894127 accept4(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(52389), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 8
[pid   727] 10:02:27.894684 read(8, "\0\27\2\0\16\0REQUEST_METHOD\3\0GET\v\0REQUE"..., 4100) = 539
[pid   727] 10:02:27.895239 write(2, "TypeError", 9TypeError) = 9
[pid   727] 10:02:27.895855 write(2, ": ", 2: ) = 2
[pid   727] 10:02:27.896568 write(2, "'NoneType' object is not iterabl"..., 33'NoneType' object is not iterable) = 33
[pid   727] 10:02:27.897286 write(2, "\n", 1
) = 1
[pid   727] 10:02:27.898149 close(8 <unfinished ...>
[pid   728] 10:02:27.898782 <... epoll_wait resumed> {{EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}}, 64, 60000) = 1
[pid   728] 10:02:27.899186 read(10, "", 4096) = 0
[pid   728] 10:02:27.899659 close(10)   = 0
[pid   728] 10:02:27.900360 brk(0x1da5000) = 0x1da5000
[pid   728] 10:02:27.900863 close(9)    = 0
[pid   728] 10:02:27.901642 brk(0x1da4000) = 0x1da4000
[pid   728] 10:02:27.902370 epoll_wait(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   727] 10:02:27.902848 <... close resumed> ) = 0
[pid   727] 10:02:27.903242 writev(2, [{"[pid: 727|app: 0|req: 2/3] 192.1"..., 201}], 1[pid: 727|app: 0|req: 2/3] 192.168.80.1 () {34 vars in 535 bytes} [Wed Aug  6 10:02:27 2014] GET /favicon.ico => generated 0 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
) = 201
[pid   727] 10:02:27.903984 epoll_wait(7,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   729] 10:02:57.889447 <... poll resumed> ) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid   729] 10:02:57.889583 write(8, "\211\0", 2) = 2
[pid   729] 10:02:57.889739 read(8, 0x1e2dbc0, 4096) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid   729] 10:02:57.889867 poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 30000 <unfinished ...>
[pid   728] 10:02:57.889954 <... epoll_wait resumed> {{EPOLLIN, {u32=8, u64=8}}}, 64, 60000) = 1
[pid   728] 10:02:57.890033 read(8, "\211\0", 4096) = 2
[pid   728] 10:02:57.890125 epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 7, {EPOLLOUT, {u32=7, u64=7}}) = 0
[pid   728] 10:02:57.890214 epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 8, {EPOLLIN, {u32=8, u64=8}}) = 0
```

Initial server output:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.6 (64bit) on [Wed Aug  6 10:07:32 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 01 August 2014 11:44:27
os: Linux-3.8.0-39-generic #58~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:33:40 UTC 2014
nodename: b05154388229
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /srv/www
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 524288
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 524288
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :80 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 740)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:43956 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 23:03:41)  [GCC 4.8.2]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x151e100
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145536 bytes (142 KB) for 2 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x151e100 pid: 
739 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 739, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 741, cores: 1)
```

Comment: It is right that the server is blocked on that call (as it is a blocking one by definition as it is waiting for websocket traffic). Have you tried with a different browser ? Can you strace the worker to understand what is going on ? And yes, reporting logs is always required :)

Comment: @roberto: Thanks.  I've tried with the 3 main browsers - all the same.  I've added logging right after the browser sends `ciao`, and it sends it immediately (in the `onmessage` function).  Thanks for the suggestion to use strace (I'm using Ubuntu, but not super familiar with it).  I've added what I think is the relevant portion of strace - you can see the 30 second timeout.  I've also included the initial server output.  I probably should also mention I'm running this within a docker container.

Comment: from the strace it looks like there is no traffic between the browser and the server. Can you add --processes 2 to the options ? i fear a second connection is unexpectedly opened.

Comment: @roberto: I've updated both the strace and server output with `--processes 2` option added.  It still waits 30 seconds for the initial response.  I think all the (main) browsers automatically send a request for a `favicon.ico` - not sure if that is the 2nd connection you're talking about?

Comment: Is this normal: `'NoneType' object is not iterable`? For second connection issue see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758014/non-blocking-concurrent-wsgi-server#comment32925576_21758014

Comment: @jwalker: I wouldn't think that error is *normal*, except I'm pretty much using an example that came with uWSGI, so I would assume it should work.  The information in your link doesn't seem related to this.  I tried with 2 processes - still blocks for 30 seconds, and all that link shows is that it processes requests sequentially - it didn't wait for a timeout to process the 2nd request (which is my issue).

Comment: @Gerrat That was purely FYI. And the example did work for me on Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit, the command line was `uwsgi --http :8080 --http-raw-body --gevent 100 --module websockets_echo`.

Comment: Could it possibly be related to [this question resolved by `--close-on-exec`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131700/python-subprocess-popen-slow-under-uwsgi)?

Comment: @Cameron:  Thanks...I'm not specifically launching a subprocess, but maybe there's an implicit one somehow.  I tried with this option though, and no change - it still waits for the timeout to respond

Comment: @Gerrat Did you run the unchanged example file with the command line from my comment above? If so, what's your browser? Did you try different OS or browser?

Comment: @jwalker: Yes.  Unchanged example file.  Command line exactly as you specified (but on Ubuntu 14.04, and running from within a docker container).  Same results with latest Chrome, IE and Firefox.  (and I *could* try outside of docker, but I need it running within docker anyway).

Comment: @Gerrat Then I suppose the only thing you can do is to narrow down the problem. BTW, I installed uWSGI into virtualenv.